# My sass not compiled when I tried it to compile from Sublime text 2?

Tags: html, css, sass, compass-sass, scout-sass

I have installed Ruby and http://mhs.github.com/scout-app/ for compile sass file.  in sublime text 2 I create a file and tried to write stylesheet.

It's not working for me.

as shown in this post http://screencasts.org/episodes/introduction-to-sass I write the code in my editor.

```
#sidebar_ad {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px; }
```

this is not working for me. someone help me on how I can compile this.
here is the error

```
/*
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "#sidebar_ad": expected selector, was "{"
        on line 1 of C:/test/style.sass

1: C:/test/style.sass

Backtrace:
C:/UniServer/www/test/content/style.sass:1
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/scss/parser.rb:1129:in `expected'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/scss/parser.rb:1066:in `expected'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/scss/static_parser.rb:21:in `parse_selector'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:310:in `visit_rule'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2096:in `send'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:98:in `visit'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2336:in `collect'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:107:in `visit_children'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:119:in `with_environment'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:106:in `visit_children'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:126:in `visit_root'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2096:in `send'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:98:in `visit'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2096:in `send'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:7:in `visit'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:140:in `compile'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:126:in `timed'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:139:in `compile'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/logger.rb:45:in `red'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:138:in `compile'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:118:in `compile_if_required'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:103:in `run'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1603:in `each'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:101:in `run'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:126:in `timed'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:100:in `run'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb:147:in `recompile'
org/jruby/RubyMethod.java:133:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:268:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:228:in `call'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/path.rb:73:in `run_callback'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/path.rb:55:in `callback_action'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/path.rb:35:in `update'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:39:in `modified'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1603:in `each'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:37:in `modified'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:18:in `refresh'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:17:in `run'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1603:in `each'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:17:in `run'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1419:in `loop'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:15:in `run'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/monitor.rb:26:in `run'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm.rb:70:in `monitor'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb:87:in `perform'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:18:in `execute'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:in `execute'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in `perform!'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Scout\bin\compass:12:in `(root)'
*/
body:before {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
  content: "Syntax error: Invalid CSS after \"#sidebar_ad\": expected selector, was \"{\"\A         on line 1 of C:/test/style.sass\A \A 1: C:/UniServer/www/test/content/style.sass"; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [Sass syntax](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#syntax), which is whitespace dependent and does not use brackets or semicolons. You have two options:

Write your code in Sass, rather than SCSS. For example:

```
#sidebar_ad
  display: block
  width: 250px
  height: 150px
```

Or change the extensions on your file from `.sass` to `.scss`.